# create new gdbinit file

Tags: gdb

Basically I am on school computer trying to use gdb. But there are way too many initial configurations, so I would like to put them into gdbinit. But gdbinit is located beyond my permission level so I can't change it. Is there a way to setup my own gdbinit in my home folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to setup my own gdbinit in my home folder?

Yes: gdb will read `$HOME/.gdbinit` if you have one.